# docker compose pull - suppress layer status information to cleanup terminal output problem due to many layers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Moving from `docker-compose` to the newer built in `docker compose` - the output is way more verbose and causes an output problem when there are a lot of container layers while using an SSH client to deploy. If there isn't enough vertical lines, it causes the ssh terminal scroll at an unreadable speed.

The original `docker-compose` seemed to show the data in a single line per service, and was clean looking.

[image]

Using the new `docker compose`:
Example of good looking input with enough vertical terminal space:

[image]

If the user does not have enough screen resolution, this basically pushes the previous output on the screen off and scrolled it out of the terminal buffer, many thousands of lines created.

[image]

One solution would be to pull each individual layer individually with something like

`docker compose ps --services |xargs -n 1 docker compose pull`

However, hoping there was a flag to just suppress the layer output, and just show a status on a single line for each service like the older docker-compose.

I am not looking to make it quiet (`-q` / `--quiet`), just not messy.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_pull/

Reference docs don't seem to have any solution here. Was curious if there was another method (without me going back to the older `docker-compose`)

Comment: I am not sure if this is related at all, but maybe something fixing your issue, would fix mine too. when using docker-compose I only have one line, which constantly shows all information:  [![docker-compose pull][1]][1]. while docker pull would show each image and its download/extracting status as a single line.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh8xU.gif

Comment: also somehow related: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8800